# Passing context to view from template: NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

Trying to pass context from template to my view (whether ad=True or False). Here's how I've tried to do it:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', home, name='bv'),
url(r'^q/', search, name='search'),
url(r'^post/', include('post.urls')),
```

**post.urls**

```
url(r'^$', views.post, name='post'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.edit, name='edit'),
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

**template**

```
<a href="{% url 'post' ad='True' %}">Proceed</a>
```

**post.views**

```
def post(request, ad=False):
    ...
```

the `ad='True'` in the template should pass onto the `views` and change the default `ad=False` to `ad=True`. Instead, I get this error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /advertise/
Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'ad': 'True'}' 
not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/$']
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass an `ad` value to a URL that doesn't expect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change route:

```
url(r'^(?P<ad>\w+)$', views.post, name='post'),
```

and better answer:

```
url(r'^(?P<ad>(True|False))$', views.post, name='post'),
```

Comment: I've updated my code. Are you able to give me a new answer? I tried your `better answer` and got this error: `NoReverseMatch at /news/
Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<ad>(True|False))$']`

Comment: I've just added it in, but it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: I created a project, and test it,
There was no problem.
Probably the problem is from the urls file

Comment: Actually it's working now, before I only had the 1 url (`url(r'^(?P<ad>(True|False))$', views.post, name='post')`) but now I have both (`url(r'^$', views.post, name='post')`) aswell. But when I go go to `post` via `{% url 'post' ad='True' %}`, the URL shows `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/True`. Can I change this to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/ad`?

Comment: yes, `url(r'^ad/(?P<ad>\w+)$', views.post, name='post'),` url result => `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/ad/True`

Comment: Thanks that's better. But is it possible to not have `True` at the end? So is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/ad` possible?

Comment: yes, By sending data by form, this can be achieved. [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/)